# Create a row based on year, half yearly, quarter

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

[image]

I would like to have the table dynamically expanded to be the following:
[image]

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is each row of the table I put in have rows added for the type of vesting tenure based on the start (Grant date) and end date (vesting end date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your example is a bit off in terms of dates, but this works for powerquery.  Use my sample data, load the entire code into home...advanced editor... to see what it is doing. Potentially change Table1 to reflect the name of your data loaded from excel with data ... from table/range ...[x]headers

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Grant Date", type date}, {"Vesting tenure", type text}, {"Vesting Period", Int64.Type}, {"Vesting end date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom"= Table.AddColumn( #"Changed Type", "End Date", 
    each let
    begin=[Grant Date],
    end=[Vesting end date],
    vtype=[Vesting tenure]
    in
    if vtype="Annually" then List.Generate(() => Date.AddYears(begin,1), each _ <= end, each Date.AddYears(_,1) )
    else if vtype="Quarterly" then List.Generate(() => Date.AddQuarters(begin,1), each _ <= end, each Date.AddQuarters(_,1) )
    else if vtype="Half Yearly" then List.Generate(() => Date.AddMonths(begin,6), each _ <= end, each Date.AddMonths(_,6) )
    else null
    ),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "End Date"),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"End Date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Start Date", each if [Vesting tenure]="Annually" then Date.AddYears([End Date],-1) else if [Vesting tenure]="Quarterly" then Date.AddQuarters([End Date],-1) else if [Vesting tenure]="Half Yearly" then Date.AddMonths([End Date],-6) else null, type date),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Grant Date", "Vesting tenure", "Vesting Period", "Vesting end date", "Start Date", "End Date"})
in  #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]

you could use Date.EndOfQuarter() or Date.EndOfMonth() around the dates if needed

Comment: "let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Grant Date", type date}, {"Vesting tenure", type text}, {"Vesting Period", Int64.Type}, {"Vesting end date", type date}}),
#"Added Custom"= Table.AddColumn( #"Changed Type", "End Date","  - I'm not able to follow this in my version.

Comment: Should i use the code from Let  each let
    begin=[Grant Date],
    end=[Vesting end date],
    vtype=[Vesting tenure]
    in
    if vtype="Annually" then List.Generate(() => Date.AddYears(begin,1), each _ <= end, each Date.AddYears(_,1) )
    else if vtype="Quarterly" then List.Generate(() => Date.AddQuarters(begin,1), each _ <= end, each Date.AddQuarters(_,1) )
    else if vtype="Half Yearly" then List.Generate(() => Date.AddMonths(begin,6), each _ <= end, each Date.AddMonths(_,6) )
    else null
    ),

Comment: let 
StDt = [#"Grant date #(lf)(dd/mm/yyyy)"],
end = [#"Vesting end date#(lf)(dd/mm/yyyy)"],
vType = [Vesting tenure]
in
if vType ="Annually" then List.Generate(() => Date.AddYears(StDt,1),each _ <= end,each Date.AddYears(_,1))
else if vType = "Quarterly" then List.Generate (() => Date.AddQuarters(StDt,1), each _ <=end, each Date.AddQuarters (_,1) )
else if vType="Half Yearly" then List.Generate(() => Date.AddMonths (StDt,6), each _ <= end, each Date.AddMonths(_,6) )
else null
),
in

Comment: I have tried the above code but " ), " before in is showing error. Not sure where i went wrong

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not able to follow all that.  If you start with my sample data (with dates entered as date values and formatted as dates), using my exact sample data column names (case matters)  and use my exact code pasted into home .. advanced editor .. (potentially adjusting the Table1 to become the name of your specific table in powerquery) then you wind up with my results

Comment: Hey - Thanks. It was mistake from my side. I have been able to use your formula to get the result i want. Thank you very much.

Comment: Need an additional help, i need to combine your formula with another formula of mine, using else if. Possible to help me out on it?

Comment: I answered the question that was asked.  If you have additional questions that are related to your original question, edit your question with additional information.  If unrelated, start a new question. Posting code in comments is hard to read

Comment: I have started it as a new question. Would be grateful if you could help me out on it